# Bootstrap modal bug after manual hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I was trying to make sure that everytime I show a modal dialog, there is no visible dialog. To make this, I'm doing:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

But doing this, when I show a modal dialog with:

```
var dlg_opts = { show: true, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' };
```

If I click on the background (backdrop) or press escape, the modal closes.
When I remove the .modal('hide'), the code works great and the modal closes only from the 'close' button.

There is an example of my modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dlgWarning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dlgWarningLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="dlgWarningLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnWarningAccept"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the dialogs:

```
var dlg_opts = { show: true, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' };

function ShowModal(id, width) {
    CloseModal();

    id = '#' + id;
    $(id).modal(dlg_opts);

    if (arguments.length == 2) $(id).css('width', width + 'px');
}

function CloseModal() {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
}
```

Anyone have an idea what could it be?
Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Here you can test it: http://www.bootply.com/123369
If you try this, you will see that the dialog closes with the esc/click on the background. Comment the $('.modal').modal('hide') and the code works great!

Comment: Your code is running well, it's something else... http://www.bootply.com/123366

Comment: The dialog shows well, but i need that the dialog closes only with the 'close' button. With this code, if click on the background or hit the esc key, the dialog closes. But if remove the $('.modal').modal('hide'), the code works great and the dialog doesn't close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you reinit the modal each time you want to call it...

So init the modal first without show them.

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123372

**JS** :

```
var dlg_opts = { show: false, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' };  // <-- HERE
$('.modal').modal(dlg_opts);                 // <-- HERE

function ShowModal(id, width) {
    CloseModal();

    id = '#' + id;
    $(id).modal('show');       // <-- HERE

    if (arguments.length == 2) $(id).css('width', width + 'px');
}

function CloseModal() {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  ShowModal('dlgWarning');
});
```

**HTML** : 
*Same as given*

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that there was a bug in Bootstrap, it's better that I made a mistake than to suffer if the framework guys make a mistake